# How to add advanced filtering expressions to Informatica Data Integration Hub

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am working in a project with Informatica Data Integration Hub. We are evaluating the idea to use FILTERS in the subscription site:

- Basic Filter expressions
- Advanced Filter Expressions

In the following picture I'm using some examples of basic expressions ( just for testing purposes, don't think about the meaning of those basic filters, they have no meaning at all ).

[image]

I cannot find anything in the documentation regarding which syntax should I follow for these advanced filter expressions. What I read in the documentation is that the filter conditions in advanced expressions should follow the rules of "Powercenter Expressions"

Can anyone tell me where I can find the documentation about the syntax of those expressions ?
Does anyone know why I can put whatever I want in the advanced expression field and it is not even evaluating for syntax purposes ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [the filtering condition doc](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-guide/filter-transformation/filter-condition.html) briefly covering the topic.

Here's a [document on working with expressions](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-guide/working-with-transformations/working-with-expressions/using-the-expression-editor.html) in Informatica.

Basically it's all pretty Excel-like. You pick a function, put arguments in brackets and that's it.

Now, the difference between basic and advanced filtering is, that in basic mode you put several conditions that need to be met at once, as Informatica is using `AND` to combine them. In case you need more anvanced `AND/OR` logic, you need to use the advanced expressions and write the complete syntax on your own.

Comment: thank you for the answer. just a question, do you know why the advanced expressions are not evaluated until runtime ? I actually can write there whatever I want  there

Comment: no, I did not try that. we have build a python framework on top of Data Integration Hub to control the publishing/subscription process, and now we are investigating how to integrate filters. I was looking to see how combine advanced expressions, but it is quite annoying the way DIH is treating those expressions. Anyway, thank you for your answer. I will accept it